# CSS flexbox: use deeply nested images to amortize changing layout dimensions

Tags: css, image, layout, flexbox, responsive-design

I can't get my head around FlexBox.

Here's what I want:

- a component divided into 3 sections vertically:

  - main view
  - status-bar
  - logs' window (toggled by a button in the status bar)
- **logs' window** max-height: 80px (might be changed to 25%/100%, based on screen size, in the future, so don't hold on to that fixed 80px value)
- **status-bar** and logs-window at the bottom of the component div and visible *AT ALL TIMES* (not overflowing vertically)
- **main view** may contain none, one or more items with a picture deep inside (it's not known how many items there will be)
- **main view items** occupy as much space as they can (stretching the image; preserving ratio): both vertically and horizontally
- **main view items** must stop stretching as soon as they reach either horizontal (either other item or sides of the component div) or vertical (the status-bar and/or top of the component div) limits
- **main view items** must not shrink beyond some fixed size (300x150px) - let them overflow if they try to.

Here's roughly what it would look like in landscape (outlines are just for clarity) - screenshot from JSFiddle
[image: layout screenshot from jsfiddle]

I've made the base layout, but the responsiveness is killing me. I'm not even sure what's blocking me: is it the image? Is it deep nesting? Is it my misuse of flexbox?

To put it simply, I want the image to amortize changes of component/screen dimensions: stretch when component div expands and shrink when component div shrinks. All that within certain bounds: min 300x150px; max - whatever the surrounding divs allow.

Can anybody more CSS-savvy help me fix the layout?

```css
/* 
https://flexbox.malven.co/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
 */

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.border {
  outline: solid black thin;
  /* border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px; */
}

.m5 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; */
}

.component {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.module1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.module1-main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.module1-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.viewport {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.viewport-thumbnail {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.log-panel {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.full-w {
  width: 100%;
}

.item2 {
  /* display: none; */
}
```

```html
<html class="border">

<body>
  <div class="component">


    <div class="container border">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="generated module1">
          <div class="module1-main border m5">

            <div class="module1-item border m5 item1">
              <div class="viewport border">
                <img src="https://www2.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif" class="viewport-thumbnail">
              </div>
              <div class="menu border">
                <button>crop</button>
                <button>resize</button>
                <span class="full-w">Image_0001.jpg</span>
                <button>share</button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="module1-item border m5 item2">
              <div class="viewport border">
                <img src="https://www2.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif" class="viewport-thumbnail">
              </div>
              <div class="menu border">
                <button>crop</button>
                <button>resize</button>
                <span class="full-w">Image_0002.jpg</span>
                <button>share</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="status-bar border m5">
        <button>show logs</button>
        <span>Found files: 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="log-panel border m5">
        <ul>
          <li>Collecting parameters</li>
          <li>In progress...</li>
          <li>Rendering</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/netikras/uzsr1p4f/79/

Side note1: HTML will be generated with angular.

Side note2: I'd really prefer staying with `<img>` over using the `<div>` with background image hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dom_ahdigital, I think I've finally made it! A slight modification to the spec: the item is always maximized. Only the picture is changing its dimensions.

My mistake was not understanding flex-grow and flex-basis completely.

Here's my solution. Works on any resizing I've tried.

```css
/* 
https://flexbox.malven.co/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bottom-windows {
  max-height: 25%;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 4 1 0;
}

.module1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.module1-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.module1-item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}

.viewport {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.viewport-thumbnail {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}

.menu {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.log-panel {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
  /* height: 80px; */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.full-w {
  width: 100%;
}

.item2 {
  /* display: none; */
}

.m5 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; */
}

.border {
  outline: black solid thin;
  /*     border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-radius: 5px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="generated module1">
      <div class="module1-main">

        <div class="module1-item m5 item1 border">
          <div class="viewport">
            <img src="https://www2.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif" class="viewport-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="menu border">
            <button>crop</button>
            <button>resize</button>
            <span class="full-w">Image_0001.jpg</span>
            <button>share</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="module1-item m5 item2 border">
          <div class="viewport">
            <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cute-penguin-icon-in-flat-style-vector-id868646936" class="viewport-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="menu border">
            <button>crop</button>
            <button>resize</button>
            <span class="full-w">Image_0002.jpg</span>
            <button>share</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-windows border">
    <div class="status-bar">
      <button>show logs</button>
    </div>
    <div class="log-panel border">
      <ul>
        <li>Collecting parameters</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Downloading</li>
        <li>Extracting</li>
        <li>In progress...</li>
        <li>Rendering</li>
        <li>Done</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/netikras/uzsr1p4f/142/

Here's how it looks now

**Wide**

[image: wide]

**Normal**

[image: normal]

**Narrow**

[image: narow]

**Very narrow and scrollable**

[image: very narrow, scrollable]

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-view">
  <div class="modules">
    <div class="module1-item border m5 item1">
      <div class="viewport border">
        <img src="https://www2.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif" class="viewport-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="menu border">
        <button>crop</button>
        <button>resize</button>
        <span class="full-w">Image_0001.jpg</span>
        <button>share</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module1-item border m5 item2">
      <div class="viewport border">
        <img src="https://www2.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif" class="viewport-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="menu border">
        <button>crop</button>
        <button>resize</button>
        <span class="full-w">Image_0002.jpg</span>
        <button>share</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="bottom-windows">
    <div class="status-bar border m5">
    <button>show logs</button>
    <span>Found files: 2</span>
  </div>

  <div class="logs-window">
    <ul>
      <li>Collecting parameters</li>
      <li>In progress...</li>
      <li>Rendering</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-view {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modules {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.module1-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.viewport {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.viewport-thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bottom-windows {
  max-height: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Do this 300px and down */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .modules {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .bottom-windows {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
}
```

**Codepen:** [Click here](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/XWRxxJJ?editors=1100)

Comment: This is very close to what I'm after. Can it stop stretching as soon as it utilizes all the visible space? i.e. the buttons should not hide behind the status-bar. The stretching should stop as soon as they reach the boundary - the status-bar.